# WMI is showing wrong version of Microsoft Access

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, version-control, wmi

We use Microsoft Access for certain database functions and as most of you already know an Access database can be very grumpy when accessed by an outdated version of Access. In order to control this I have an appliance that can track version number's and update outdated verions if need be. I noted something strange that is happening on all of my workstations.

On a work station if I run **wmic** and then run the following:

```
product get name, version
```

It shows the following version info:

```
Name                                                 Version:
Microsoft Office Access MUI (English) 2010           14.0.6029.1000
```

Yet when I open Microsoft Access and go to **File->Help** it shows version:

```
Version:14.0.6112.5000
```

I know the version number that is showing up in Access is correct and the one showing up in **wmic** is incorrect. This is happening both on Windows 7 and XP machines. Is there a way for me to update the WMI since I rely on that info for version control? Why is it showing such an old version even though it has been updated?

**EDIT1:**

When I look at the version of MSACCESS.exe it shows `14.0.6024.1000`, which is an even older version of access! Where exactly is WMIC looking for the version number? Is it a registry key that can be edited?

**EDIT2:**

I have found that the version number at `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Userdata\userSID\00004109510090400000000000F01FEC\DisplayVersion` seems to be where WMIC is pulling it's verison number from, which makes sense. Where does the **Access->File->Help** menu pull the version number from then? Does it look at the latest service pack exe for this data?

Comment: overall this ends up being a good question, I'm thinking its one of the many office dll's but I don't know which one.

Comment: wonder if using the version (not the display version) info located at that reg key would be more appropriate?

Comment: if you had procmon you could see which key wmic is using, but I'm quite sure its the regkey listed below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that **Access->File->Help** finds its version number from `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\MSO.dll`. So whenever Microsoft Office updates it updates this file's version number but not the registry entry noted above. There is no viable way of getting WMIC to read the correct Access version without changing the registry key listed above manually.

Comment: you could use wmic to query the version of the file.

Answer (score 0):

what result do you get if you do the following

get-itemproperty "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | ft displayname, displayversion

Comment: When I try to run that command in wmic I get: `get - Alias not found.` I am pretty new to wmic so I am not sure if I am doing it wrong.

Comment: oops sorry are you on a windows 7 machine if so run this within powershell with an elevated prompt.

Comment: I have ran this on powershell with administrator rights and I get no output from the command.

Comment: get-itemproperty "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | ft displayname, displayversion

Comment: ah crap serverfault is removing the last backslash! so just prior to the * add a backslash

Comment: ok corrected the original post

Comment: OK, I ran the command at it shows the version number for Access to be `14.0.6029.1000` which is the incorrect version.

Comment: I'd look at the actual .exe file for access and check its version.

Comment: Checking the file version of the .exe it shows: `14.0.6024.1000`, so an even older version than what wmic is showing.